# MergeOption in WCF Data Services

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I have two similar, but different Odata service operation calls (same service operation, different parameters) executing in an event handler.  Stepping through the code, I can see that each query's CreateQuery<> call produces different query URI's and that when requested via a browser, the results returned are correct.  NOW TO WEIRD STUFF! The second query always returns the same results as the first unless I I specify MergeOption = OverwriteChanges.  Here's a simplified view of how I'm calling the svc operations:

```
List<Listing> whereToDine = Container.CreateQuery<Listing>("SearchListings")                        
                                                 .AddQueryOption("listingTypeIds", "'14'")
                                                 .AddQueryOption("cityId", CityId.ToString())
                                                 .AddQueryOption("radius", SearchRadius.ToString())
                                                 .AddQueryOption("skipIndex", "0")
                                                 .AddQueryOption("pageSize", (PageSize * NumPages).ToString())                                                                        
                                                 .AddQueryOption("sortType", "'name'").ToList<Listing>();
```

Anybody have any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client does tracking of entities (assuming Listing is an entity type). So the Container (DataServiceContext) holds references to all the entities returned by it when queries are evaluated.

This is necessary to be able to track changes to the entities so that when you call SaveChanges the context knows which entities needs to send a request to the server to update.

Currently the client does not perform property level tracking, so it only knows if an entity as whole changed or not. Not if a single property on it changed.

As a result when it reads data coming from a server and the response contains an entity which the client already tracks, it has to decide if the data coming from server are the ones to use or the values on the client should be used (basically at that point it has two versions of the same entity, one from client, one from server).

The MergeOption is the setting telling the client what to do in this case.

The default is that the client values win, the thinking is such that if you changed some values on the client, you don't want the ones from the server to overwrite your changes until you commit them through SaveChanges.

So in the first call to the service operation the client obtains the entities from the server (For the first time) and you get your results. In the second call, you probably get the same entities, but with new values in them. But the default setting on the client is to keep the client values and so the evaluation of the query effectively drops the incoming data from the server.

The MergeOption is the right way to tell the client what to do.